# Sending analytics hits to another endpoint

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Firebase Analytics question: is it possible to duplicate events/payloads to another endpoint besides the Firebase's own? Let's say GTM server side or something completely custom.

I know it can be done with the Measurement Protocol-based implementation but what about any of the SDKs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easily with wrappers. Wrapping compiled SDKs is a very simple way to extend their functionality. The idea here is that you don't use your SDKs directly from the code. Instead, you're making quick wrapping classes that import the SDKs in question and mirror the SDKs' functions with their own. Now, from the code, you only use the mirrors and you only import your class rather than the SDK.

Then, you can extend your wrapper to a great extent, making your .send() function to also sanitize payloads, normalize data, send it to wherever else you want it in.

There's just no need for the core sdk to allow something that is so easily achieved with wrappers, especially considering that wrappers usage is considered a very good practice and I often see them in place with various analytics SDKs even when analysts failed to request them.

Again, if MP is implemented via a compiled SDK, then you're facing the same problem.

Comment: Hi @BNazaruk thank you for this answer. Any extre details or examples would be highly appreciated. I can see how this could be done with the JS SDK but let's say with Unity I'm not sure where to start. Thanks!

Comment: Never done it with Unity, but I wouldn't be able to share my production code either way. Doesn't Unity have a similar to swift's, kotlin's and Java's OOP model?